# JPEG Image Loading Slow Compared to Browser

Tags: android, image, performance, jpeg

I am making an application which displays JPEG images in `Grid` and `ListView`.

For example, 500x500, 640x640, 300x300 (various different sizes).

I have been struggling to find a way to improve the loading speed.
I have been using Picasso, UIL, Volley library but there wasn't significant change in speed (too slow).

I tried the following test many times:

1. All devices are connected to Wi-Fi, and all images are stored in a web server.
2. Images are in JPEG format, and file sizes are between 150–250 kb each.
3. Desktop/Laptop using the internet browser to load 10 550x550 images.
4. Android phone using the internet browser (Google Chrome) to load 10 550x550 images.
5. Android phone using the application load 10 550x550 images

The result is hilarious.

I typed the same URL to show these 10 images; it took around 2 seconds to download and display all the images on the browser (both on the laptop and the Android device). But it's taking each image 2-3 seconds to display this in the application.

Please provide advice on how to improve speed.

Comment: You need to provide code. We don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: your question is too broad until you show us some code. I also used Picasso a lot and loaded tons of hi-res images pretty fast. In general, we woud need to see your `Adapter` implementation, your data model and how you init/instantiate your image loaders.

Comment: The problem may be related to connection or download latency, assuming the browsers are downloading the images in parallel and the app does the image downloads serially.  How long does it take to download a **single** image via browser?  If it's about 2 seconds, the problem is likely on your web server or somewhere else in you infrastructure  (slow to access an image file, or slow reverse DNS lookup for a request, for example).